# Web monitoring variables are not URL-encoded

Tags: url, web, encoding, monitoring, zabbix

it's in the documentation but want do it automatically. Web page generating token and I need send it with login and pass to success login.

There is some more info: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2074 , but it's old patch, I don't know how to install it to zabbix 3.0.

Do you have some resolution how to encode regex variable?

Answer (score 1):

As the issue history reveals, this feature is not available yet. You will have to either update the patch to work with your version of Zabbix, or wait for somebody else to do so.

If you have an account in the Zabbix issue tracker, make sure to vote on that issue (the link in the upper right corner).